# Python: Create a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: python

```
def convert_c(celsius):
    c = float(celsius)
    c = (c-32)*5/9
    return(c)

for
c = (temp-32)*5/9
```

Returns an invalid syntax message

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @bob123, I tried to format it for you.. why is there a ```for``` with nothing after it ?

Comment: `for` - try removing that line.

Comment: You're never actually calling your function.

Comment: Also, in order to get the result you need to call the function and pass it some value `convert_c(value)`. Your last line will cause `NameeError` because temp is not defind, so remove it

Answer (score 1):

```py
def convert_fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    celsius = float(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
    return celsius
def convert_celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = (float(celsius) * 9 / 5 + 32)
    return fahrenheit
```

Here's a code I wrote to convert fahrenheit to celsius, and celsius to fahrenheit

Answer (score 0):

```py
def convertCelsius(fahrenheit):
    celsius = (float(fahrenheit) - 32) * (5/9)
    return celsius
```

The 5/9 needs to be in brackets

Comment: Whether that's in brackets or not doesn't make a difference to the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code:

```
def convert_c(f):
    f = (f-32)*5/9
    return round(f,2)

temp = *insert temperature of your choice*

print(f"{convert_c(temp)}°F")
```

Remember that the parameter which goes in the brackets of `convert_c()` is actually the temperature in fahrenheit, so it would be clearer to call that `f` rather than `celsius`. Additionally, you do not need to change it to a float value, since this is done on entry as you can see in the line `temp = float(input("Enter temperature in fahrenheit: "))`. Your equation is great, and you're returning the right thing, but I would probably round the answer, just so it's a bit more readable. Depends what you're after though.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi Emma, I was trying to do it without the interactive input option. Just the conversion. Can I take out the "input" option?

Comment: of course! all you would have to do is change the value of temp to whatever number you wanted, so for example ```temp = 100```